# Convexity without Differentiability

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

I believe this proof will come quickly to someone working with early calculus concepts of differentiability. I can feel how we are working with the "change of a change", but I'm not sure what lemma or definition I should be manipulating this too.

Without assuming $f$ is differentiable, I need to show the following:

If $b > a$ and $f$ is convex then
$$ f(b) - f(a) \geq \frac{1}{\lambda} [ f (\lambda b) - f(\lambda a) ]$$ where $ \lambda \in (0,1)$ is abritrary.

Thank you
:) <3

Edit: Of the three definitions of convexity I use regularly, the only one that doesn't require differentiability is: $$ f(\alpha x + (1 - \alpha)y) \leq \alpha f(x) + (1- \alpha) f(y) $$ where $ \alpha \in (0,1)$

Also, the assumption $ \underline{ a,b \in \mathbb{R_+}}$ is required.

Comment: What is the definition of convexity? What have you tried? You say $f$ isn’t differentiable and yet suggest calculus should be used. Once again, what is the definition of convexity?

Comment: P.S. You might clarify the statement. It certainly holds when $b=a$ for every function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $f$ is convex and $x<y<z$ then
$$
f(y)\le \frac{f(z)(y-x)+f(x)(z-y)}{z-x}\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$
f(y)-f(x)\le\frac{f(z)(y-x)+f(x)(z-y)-f(x)(z-x)}{z-x}=\frac{f(z)(y-x)-f(x)(y-x)}{z-x}\,,
$$
or equivalently,
$$\tag{1}
\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\le\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}\,.
$$
Similarly, one shows that for $w<x\le y<z$ the inequalities
$$\tag{2}
\frac{f(x)-f(w)}{x-w}\le\frac{f(y)-f(w)}{y-w}\le\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\le\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}\le
\frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}
$$
hold.

***Case 1:*** $\lambda a<a\le\lambda b<b\,.$

From (2) with $w=\lambda a,x=a,y=\lambda b,z=b$ we get
$$\tag{3}
\frac{f(\lambda b)-f(\lambda a)}{\lambda(b-a)}\le\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
$$
from which the desired inequality
$$\tag{4}
f(b)-f(a)\ge\frac{f(\lambda b)-f(\lambda a)}{\lambda}
$$ follows.

***Case 2:*** $\lambda a<\lambda b<a<b\,.$

From (2) with $w=\lambda a,x=\lambda b,y=a,z=b$ we get again (3) and (4).

Comment: I asked the OP to clarify, but it seems $b>a$ is the desired conclusion, given the criterion.

Comment: @TedShifrin . OP's wording does indeed suggest that the desired inequality is $b>a$. I will vote to close the question when this doesn't get clarified.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @econHanson: If this is what you're looking for, it's certainly NOT what you said. This is NOT proving that $b>a$ (which, as I've told you, is wrong, anyhow, since the best you can get is $b\ge a$). This is ASSUMING $b>a$.

Comment: @econHanson . I agree with TedShifrin. Please study in detail my edit of your question above to reflect what you were apparently looking for.

Comment: I see now. If the original inequality is strick, then we can get to $a<b$ with it and convextity. However, with a weak inequality, best we can do is $a \leq b$ or we can only go the other direction.

Comment: What is the "original inequality" ? Is $a<b$ your assumption or your conclusion ? If it is  the latter it is wrong. Even a conclusion of $a\le b$ is wrong (see copper.hat's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Is suspect there is something missing from the question as it is not true as stated.

This has nothing to do with differentiability as such.

The underlying fact is that $f$ is convex **iff** the secants are non decreasing, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_one_variable.

Let $f(x) = \max(0,-x-1)$ which is convex, $a=2, b=-2, \lambda = {1 \over 2}$.
Then $f(b)-f(a) = 1-0 = 1$, whereas
${f(\lambda b)-f(\lambda a) \over \lambda } = 0$.

Howeve, $b<a$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I am working in $ \mathbb{R}_+ $, so I should add $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_+$. I think that should fix the issue.

Comment: It will, but that invalidates my work.