# Proving that a function is increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

1. Suppose $f$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a, b]$ and $f^{\prime \prime}(x)>0$ on $(a, b)$, and define
   $$
   \phi(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} .
   $$
   Show that $\phi(x)$ is increasing on $(a, b)$. Hint: Show that
   $$
   \phi^{\prime}(x)=\frac{f^{\prime}(x)-\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}}{x-a}
   $$

Here is what I have gotten so far (tried to use the quotient rule to show what the functions derivative is.

$$\frac{(x-a)(f'(x)) - (f(x) - f(a))}{(x-a)^2}$$

Is this in the right direction? I know that if I cancel out the top $x-a$ term with one of the bottom ones that leaves me with $$\frac{(f'(x)) - (f(x)-f(a))}{(x-a)}$$ But I still need an $(x-a)$ for the top second term. Any thoughts?

Comment: The hint formula for $\phi'$ is correct, but your quotient rule result is not--check your arithmetic.

Comment: Do you know what to do once you have $\phi'$?

Comment: Hint: use that $f$ will be convex. It is even strictly convex btw. [Spoiler](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4571167/949989).

Comment: The arithmetic mistake is obvious. But I don't actually know how to proceed after we have $\phi'.$ Hmm.... Unless we are allows to use "$f''(x)>0 \implies f$ convex", where "convex" means "the secant line is above the curve" definition.

Comment: By the Lagrange theorem $[f(x)-f(a)]/(x-a)=f'(\xi)$ for some $a<\xi<x.$ Hence $f'(x)>f'(\xi)$ as $f'$ is strictly increasing due to $f''>0.$

Comment: I don't see where I went wrong in the arithmetic could I have some help on that @NickF

Comment: @snell_express "*if I cancel out the top x−a term...*" $\;$ Check the next step, you lost a factor along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Once you fix the error in your quotient rule, the simplest way to approach this problem is to ask, where does the second derivative come in?

In the formula for $\phi(x)$, notice that we could apply the Mean Value Theorem to $f$ and say there exists a $c_x \in (a,x)$ such that $\phi(x) = f'(c_x)$. In particular, this means that
$$
\phi'(x) = \frac{f'(x) - \phi(x)}{x-a} = \frac{f'(x) - f'(c_x)}{x-a}.
$$
But we can apply MVT again to the numerator, and say there exists a $c_x^* \in (c_x,x)$ such that $f'(x) - f'(c_x) = f''(c_x^*)(x-c_x)$. That is,
$$
\phi'(x) = \frac{x-c_x}{x-a}f''(c_x^*) > 0.
$$
Since this works for any arbitrary $x \in (a,b)$, we conclude that $\phi'$ is positive on $(a,b)$, and thus $\phi$ is increasing there.